# Find the integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What are the pairs $(A,N)$ where $A,N$ are integers such that the following equation is satisfied:

$\large A=\frac{-6+\sqrt{144-12N^2}}{6}$

I know that we should have:

$k^2=144-12N^2$ for some integer $k$.

How do I proceed from here? Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried calculating $144-12N^2$ for a few values of $N$?

Comment: You must have $12N^2 \leqslant 144$, which, dividing by $12$ becomes $N^2 \leqslant 12$. There aren't many $N$ to test.

Comment: @ChrisEagle that is not an elegant solution and I cannot justify why only those solutions can exist.

Comment: @DanielFischer so we have the inequality $-3 \leq N \leq 3$ and we also deduce that $N$ has to be a multiple of $3$ for solutions to exist. So we check for only $3$ values namely $-3,0,3$.

Comment: And since the expression is even in $N$, we need to check only $0,\, 3$.

Comment: And it satisfies for both the values, and we are done. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that $$6|\sqrt{144-12N^2}\Rightarrow 144-12N^2=36k^2$$ for some integer $k$ . Then it follows $$N^2=3(4-k^2)\Rightarrow N=3m$$ for some integer $m$. So ultimately we get $$4=3m^2+k^2$$ which implies the only solutions as $ k={}_{-}^{+}1,\ m=0,{}_{-}^{+}1 $. So 
$$N={}_{-}^+3,0$$ and consequently $$A=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
 0,-2 & \mbox{if}  N={}_{-}^+3\\
 1,-3 & \mbox{if} N=0 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

---

Comment: How about $N=0$?

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**First condition:** $144-12N^2\ge0$

$$72\ge N^2$$
$$N\in(-4,4)$$

**Second condition**:  $144-12N^2$ should be a perfect square

As $N\in Z$, so $N$ can be $\{0,3,-3\}$

**Third condition**:- $\sqrt{144-2N^2}$ should be divisible by $6$

For $N=0$, $\sqrt{144}=12$ which is divisible by $6$

For $N=3$, $\sqrt{144-128}=6$ which is divisible by $6$

For $N=-3$, $\sqrt{144-128}=6$ which is divisible by $6$

So there are total three valid pairs $(0,1),(3,0),(-3,0)$